# How to set a unique constraint on 2 columns - one column being mapped to distinct values of another

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So I have a table like this:

```
Internal ID | SAP ID  | . . . 
------------+---------+
1           | 254     | . . .
2           | 5       | . . .
2           | 5       | . . .
3           | 8       | . . .
```

As you see there's always just one SAP ID for each distinct internal ID.
For example, you shouldn't be able to add another entry with:

```
Internal ID | SAP ID  | . . .
------------+---------+
2           | 6       | . . .
```

As 2 is already mapped to 5 so to say one shouldn't be able to enter the above example.

How can I set a constraint like this ?

Comment: You have to Use CHECK constraints.

Comment: The answer is simple - Don't do that. It is a denormalization and consequently comes with an update anomaly that must then be prevented in code. Use a VIEW to associate the SAP ID with the Internal ID in secondary tables.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens As far as I understand it that doesn't apply when I'm making an "import" database available for a user to fill directly.

Comment: You tell me - you are here on the forum struggling with the update anomaly caused by the decision to denormalize a group of tables, and asking for how to deal with this circumstance. **The way to deal with this circumstance is to normalize, so that the Update Anomaly disappears.** Proceed otherways at your own risk and labour.

Answer (score 1):

Your table structure is not good.  You are allowing duplicate rows in the table, but only under some circumstances.  Instead, you should have a mapping table between the two ids that does not permit duplicates:

```
create table InternalIds (
    InternalId int not null primary key,
    SAPId int
);
```

This pretty much solves the problem, because it allows only *one* row per internal id.  I've phrased this as a separate table, but you can add the column into an existing table, if you like.

Then, when you want the *specific* SAP ids for a given internal id, just look it up.

Answer (score -1):

You should use COMPOSITE KEY constraint. To set the constraint use the sample query

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.testRequest
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TestRequest 
PRIMARY KEY (Internal ID, SAP ID)
```